# How to configure the fields to hide in cakePHP debug() function?

Tags: cakephp

in CakePHP, when applying the debug function on a User model :

```
debug($user);
```

we get a result that hide the login or password.

```
    'User' => array(
        'login' => '*****',
        'id' => (int) 2,
        'pwd' => 'fjiogjfdlmgjdomngdjm',
        'avatar' => null,
        'prenom' => 'Fake',
        'nom' => 'Admin',
        'email' => 'blabla@domain.fr',
        'i18n_code_appli' => '',
        'numtel' => ''
    ),
```

How could we configure what model has that field hidden or not ?

Like you can see in the example below, as password field named 'pwd', it is not hidden, but login is.

And this is my actual case. I would want to toggle this to view 'login' and hide 'pwd' in debug mode.

Comment: I don't think it should be doing that. Are you sure that the login field is not literally "*****"? Have you checked it in the database?

Comment: Note that debug() cloaks login/password fields etc for security reasons (kinda nonsense if you ask me, but nontheless you can check the code to confirm). It will not do that for custom fields like pwd. Either way this is totally irrelevant as long as you don't output it anywhere this can be seen as non-issue. Just don't debug() output it permanently.

Comment: Just use var_dump() instead of debug() if you have to check the password hash. I have had the same problem a long while ago and I thought I just used var_dump() for that case. You won't keep the function-call in place anyway so it won't do any harm (I guess).

Comment: @Juhana no, login doesn't equal to ****, this happen on all records

Comment: @mark I understand your thoughts. In fact I don't use it permanently but occasionally and with the contain behavior on nested data.

Comment: @Jelmer As these fields are contained in a nested data, its not really practical to use var_dump on a specific field into the tree.

Comment: If it is deeply nested data, consider using the CakePHP debug kit. https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit :) It has a variables tab in which you can see all the set variables. Kinda handy if you ask me.

Comment: @Jelmer Thank you it makes the job perfectly!

Comment: @RémiB. Should I add it as an answer so that you can mark it as an answer or isn't it the answer you were looking for? - ps. what was the solution? var_dump() or debug_kit?

Comment: @Jelmer Yes of course. I think debug_kit is the best solution because indeed, debug() is not configurable, and debug kit is there to going further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As agreed in the comments of [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24034657/1110760), I'll add my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034657/how-to-configure-the-fields-to-hide-in-cakephp-debug-function?noredirect=1#comment37056574_24034657) as an answer.*

---

Just use `var_dump()` instead of `debug()` if you have to check the password hash. I have had the same problem a long while ago and I thought I'd used var_dump then. I guess you aren't keeping the call to `debug()` in the code on release so it shouldn't do any harm.

Or you could use the CakePHP Debug Kit. It has a list of all the set variables which you can collapse and extend. That way you have a clear overview of all the data in a deep multidimensional array.